# lxml.isoschematron cannot compile test expression

Tags: python, xml, lxml, schematron, tei

I am attempting to use an [RNG schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bodleian/consolidated-tei-schema/master/msdesc.rng) to [validate XML against RelaxNG and Schematron rules with lxml](https://lxml.de/validation.html#id2). This is a common arrangement for more complex forms of XML, such as TEI, but it is surprisingly difficult to find a reliable validator with minimal dependencies. I keep receiving `lxml.etree.XSLTParseError` errors on test expressions that work elsewhere. Is there a way to work around this?

This is a minimal example, based on the lxml documentation:

```py
from io import StringIO

from lxml import etree, isoschematron

f = StringIO(
    """\
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" >
  <pattern id="origDate">
    <title>Original date rule</title>
    <rule context="Total">
      <assert test="@calendar and (@when or @notBefore or @notAfter or @from or @to) and string-length(normalize-space(string())) gt 0">A test rule.</assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
"""
)

sct_doc = etree.parse(f)
schematron = isoschematron.Schematron(sct_doc)
```

The full error message is `lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: xsl:when : could not compile test expression '@calendar and (@when or @notBefore or @notAfter or @from or @to) and string-length(normalize-space(string())) gt 0'`.

Comment: The Schematron rules I see in the linked RNG sample to me suggest that for Schematron evaluation an implementation supporting XPath 2 or later needs to be used, meaning in many cases some implementation based on Saxon or other XPath 2 or later implementations; I don't know, however, how that is usually done in the context of RNG plus Schematron and in the world of TEI and Python.

Comment: Of course it should be possible to extract the `pattern` elements from the linked RNG schema and insert them into Schematron schema root element; then, in the Python world, these days you can use SaxonC (saxonche is a Python package) to compile the Schematron to XSLT (using Schxslt or the ISO Schematron XSLT 2.0 stylesheet) and then apply the generated XSLT to perform the Schematron validation against any instance (TEI document, I suppose).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the root issue! It sounds as if `saxonche` is the answer.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/robbert-harms/pyschematron but the author says it is not yet ready, hopes to finish it around summer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>` instead of `gt`.

`gt` is in XPath 2.0 and later. 'lxml' is presumably working with XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0, which don't support `gt`.

Compare https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-RelationalExpr and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-ComparisonExpr

Comment: In fact `string-length(normalize-space(string())) gt 0` can be simplified to `normalize-space()`; or if you find that too cryptic, `normalize-space() != ''`.